# Cron Job WordPress: Doesn't Work in a Custom Plugin

Tags: wordpress, cron

I created a plugin for generating a CSV using the custom fields of certain pages. The generation of the CSV file must occur either by clicking on a button (and this works correctly) or by a cron job that executes the function once a day at a certain time (this does not work).

How can I solve it? or what can I check?

Below I leave you the complete code.

Thank you

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: #
Plugin URI: #
Description: #
Version: 1.0
Author: #
Author URI: #
*/

add_action('admin_menu', 'registra_pagina_opzioni');
add_action('genera_csv_tratte_event', 'genera_csv_tratte');


register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'schedula_generazione_csv');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'rimuovi_schedulazione_csv');

function registra_pagina_opzioni() {
    add_management_page(
        'Genera Feed CSV', 
        'Genera Feed CSV', 
        'manage_options', 
        'genera-feed-csv', 
        'pagina_opzioni_genera_feed_csv'
    );
}

function pagina_opzioni_genera_feed_csv() {
    if (isset($_POST['genera_csv'])) {
        genera_csv_tratte();
        echo '<div class="updated"><p>Il file CSV è stato generato manualmente.</p></div>';
    }
    ?>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h2>Genera Feed CSV</h2>

        
        <form method="post" action="">
            <input type="submit" name="genera_csv" value="Genera CSV" class="button button-primary">
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function genera_csv_tratte() {
    // code to generate file
}


function schedula_generazione_csv() {
    if (!wp_next_scheduled('genera_csv_tratte_event')) {
        wp_schedule_event(strtotime('23:00:00'), 'daily', 'genera_csv_tratte_event');
    }
}

function rimuovi_schedulazione_csv() {
    $timestamp = wp_next_scheduled('genera_csv_tratte_event');
    wp_unschedule_event($timestamp, 'genera_csv_tratte_event');
}
```

If I run the cronjob via a "cronjob manager" plugin, the function runs fine and the file generates, so that's not the problem.

I deactivated and reactivated the plugin so I could "reset" the existing cron jobs.

Comment: Welcome! This is most likely because `wp_schedule_event` is not truly a cron job. It will only trigger if someone visits the site after the scheduled event time has passed. It doesn't just run on an interval. There are ways to setup a third-party to ping your site everyday after a certain time to force the cron to run - like a script on your server. If your site is cached, that will also present some difficulty to register a site visit.